# Little challenge for y'all

Tags: cipher

Ciphertext: `WFREZOBRHCESTIKVBZEOGOAXZGGHTQFADLGEPBHXDIRSMELEQBGODKAIVRBTTMMEEJRSMNXFXRAEUBAIUMSUEEXVHIREZQVSXJQSQMMLDRVTIWNPGZRWAZMLDJBTFWVSOJRCFWKWDLQPDWUEEJLBQTHRJCQIZIFYVCHMTIKVBQNIPPXEJPREPJNXLFNDMNXIOGAGTMPEQRRDUBBRVRNLXMWFDAXIZPXEGOHADBXVVRUEDMPEVQBMQBAMQECRAXKMHRBRUIEMQRUEIIRLHJBOWMWEWGGIFBHSNRUEFEHSISFEUOAXHCAHACKWWMPRMKDMWZHTIQMLDQDUMLKSQMSSBMVMDJSODKXWIPBMTMKIIMEDSCTVGGAGGAMLHPRWMAGSUGFKFPTXPWNTFIVOHPFWACEHUCGUDVBEVIRDTIKVBFBWTMZSWYHTTWKMVYGIAVMSEPVNSBAIPGAARBXVDJYWQAMMOJJEDMGXVSEEFPTXWFRRQEXVHYAYZIMMRLNLEMVYUGGYUUIPLANTUWGWESGHQRNWWJNUSPXHDLQPAQGXHBBUFBAEWURWQZXGXPEEZBECVMZEIPXVHSADQZGIZQPOFTTRGWNRPIGHLRUAPVMXDIRNYCVLWMPOZDBRFCGHQPHQHQRCDMMEUWGHMBPIQCRDQLTTUMCEDAXGXPVTKBXEPRBGGIKHWFRSTIWSZYECTQOIDLBTTMKXHYZORIGEOWFTEPTHFYZPQLHRRLRSULXSIRUEOWFQDLQCQVMVHYADIMKIFMZBUVZXKPBUSPUPDAXSOWWIEMBKMVWXKCSEIXTTHPFTTIMSXPNNFIZSQGFTEPTHOCSTNMAMQBSRAUMMPCGOFQFIRLRORBAIWPBOBMKWZMHLPIKVLTRWUBAEQMGHQZUSAMSDAKNQHLGSDMMVLCIEPNKSPYFIPMKSRKBRMUHVHBVSFIGXSYETANMLHYECTQOIOYOYDQGXKKBSFKHYOBOEPMVVBNGEPYNMFIYYGABRJRUEEBTRGYEDFWHPVZYAOSAEGSFEPIKEQERORKBTKCESUVVPXBVNSANFVRVTGBBSQYADFZTRVNBSUBBSQYADMTFSVRAOZMHJLRJAEPTVGCETTIGEYGTEZMKILRJAEAESZQVNOMMLHNNPQZLLDBGONMAEQBYEPEBXKANRQIGHWFRSOIGRHPGHQGAEGZEOGOAXZGGHFPXQZYFNFZXEOJLDQABKQCQFAZMLLQFODBHJZMEKMKHYSJRORBBQHQGHQGVEOJRDTIKVBMIEDBHWKMJHUULSPCGHUVZEQBUEDMTHLRAOPLXHWFRNOIFIEYPKFWPSUIBNFPXWDDRAEEXARPXEPEXXDJXEPIUSXRJHMBBLDBYEMZGIGABNOMKRLLTTTMLLDBBWMZVLLTRAZLUPDAXSEMVVHRJODSYSURUESWOIULZEZBAEUPLDULGXJGIEYCVLDUNYNCMMKYQARMXPLLTHQPTHKCNRPAHQHMSTTQLWWMEYNMYSUCNNPIYXHPGHQAXGRLQTUUXLHUNSOIEPHBNWMGAIVCRMQLIEURVCGTTVOWGHACZLWDHLUILOHBUIYEAEWUNSNWMLHPVNSPBQESGHQETWHLWOKQGKECVNSKKCSRVCTMLELBFOYMMLLLTANWNXWFRBMTDEQNEONTXQWFRNYCMXHPRDEBXZHRHRZMKWSMRMTQLXRPLLQALSQFVSFWKCUCCEMBLMWQRLRPTWWMAOAVXPLQGEZABGRSYDZBZIWYAYFPBRJKBRQWNXRDUIYMQGHNGSAUXGRKZEZBTFRSGWAZDMQEOAOSPEUBFTTZHYJFGHQXTTHPFSAQMYULRDYGTXWCATUWGFDAXTABAIVYSEFPXQHAUAZQLQZYFBUOZIUYADTMTZLCETTIGAHURRQCLIGRBAZLAEGZREZMQUXGFIFMECPYQEFPXGRKCOZMGXVQYIPIEQRQGNAQLIOCFSXGHZHPBNQIGSWFRRMVWXKCYOGLVPLAXSUPTHKCNRPEAIQKBVUVZXKCGANTXWHCZEPBHFHRUEDMLYORBFMJKSNCACAOMSRRUCMBVLLLTOZBAIEYERQTLXKYGMMLXMWCIEZPTVGCETAWIIQUUAFTBXWJRNAQLIWFRLAKDXXKOLQZLQDBRWMAAIDTVLKLBWJSVSQLTRGURHMLMSUCFODBMSGPVLXQGKDQZAXTTGFCFSTWEIWMCAEATRHLQOEKHTHGATABAILLGEDQHVLRJAEILAHJYWQPTHWYXEZBAIHDSODBLMWRVNSQGXKCZIPLEIRDNPUTXSILBTQJHSNQNNPXTTHPFWMATWPYYLBQEIRDJHMBESRIRDXQDIHVCLAABZHQGHQATJHUNSDQZKHBGONTHALDJEYIWIDKVSFIDI`

Good luck!

Comment: Source: [National Cipher Challenge](https://www.cipherchallenge.org/) 2018, puzzle 9A. A third-party archive has the [cipher and solution](https://github.com/themaddoctor/BritishNationalCipherChallenge/blob/master/2018/9A/).

Answer (score 6):

This is a

> Vigenere cipher

with key

> dynamite

When you decode it with that, you get

> THE ENGINEERS HARRY BROUGHT WITH HIM WANTED TO TAKE SAWS AND TORCHES TO THE TABLE SAFE BUT NEITHER OF US WERE KEEN I COULD SEE THAT IT WOULD BE WORTH A LOT TO COLLECT OR SAND PROBABLY BELONGED IN A MUSEUM HARRY SAID HE AGREED BUT I HAD A FEELING HE WANTED IT INSTALLED BACK IN HEADQUARTERS THERE WAS SOMETHING PROPRIETORIAL IN THE WAY HE LOOKED AT IT IT TOOK THE TWO OF US EIGHTEEN HOURS TO CRACK IT BUT WITH A SQUADRON OF SPECIAL FORCES FROM HERE FORD GUARDING US THERE WAS NO RISK THAT MY ATTACKERS WOULD RETURN I ASKED HARRY HOW HE GOT AUTHORISATION TO BRING THEM IN AFTER ALL WE STILL WERENT SURE THAT THERE WERE ANY NATIONAL SECURITY IMPLICATIONS BUT HE JUST LAUGHED AND POINTED OUT THAT WE WERE CURRENTLY SOMEWHERE UNDER NEW SCOTLAND YARD AND IT HADNT TAKEN MUCH TO CONVINCE THE HOME SECRETARY THAT WE NEEDED A PROPER SECURITY TEAM TO GUARD THE SHADOW ARCHIVE ANOTHER TEAM OF ANALYSTS HAD CAMPED ON ONE SIDE OF THE COMMAND CENTRE AND WERE COMBING THROUGH BLACKS CODE BOOK AND THE FEW PAPERS THAT OUR ANTAGONISTS HAD LEFT BEHIND FROM TIME TO TIME ONE OF THE TROOPERS WOULD ARRIVE WITH ANOTHER BOX OF DOCUMENTS RETRIEVED FROM A SIDE ROOM OR AMORED ISTANT PART OF THE ARCHIVE LABYRINTH MOST COULD BE DECRYPTED QUICKLY USING THE STANDARD TOOLS BLACK HAD USED A RANGE OF CIPHERS INCLUDING SUBSTITUTION AND TRANSPOSITION AND ALMOST NONE OF IT WAS HARDER THAN A VIGENERE IT WAS SLOW SINCE THE PAPERS HAD TO BE HANDLED WITH CARE AND THE SCANNER THEY HAD BROUGHT WITH THEM WASNT REALLY DESIGNED FOR THIS SORT OF WORK A COUPLE OF TIMES THEY CALLED HARRY OVER TO SHOW HIM SOMETHING AND HE READ IT NODDED THEN CAME BACK TO WORK ON THE SAFE AS WE WORKED WE TALKED ABOUT WHAT I HAD LEARNED CONCERNING THE SHADOW ARCHIVE AND BLACKS SECRET WORK FOR THE GOVERNMENT HARRY DIDNT GIVE MUCH AWAY BUT I HAD A FEELING HE HAD HEARD SOME OF THIS STORY BEFORE AND AFTER THE SECOND TIME HE WAS CALLED AWAY HE SEEMED PARTICULARLY THOUGHTFUL I ASKED HIM WHAT WAS BOTHERING HIM BUT HE WAS ENJOYING BEING CRYPTIC HE SAID SOMETHING ABOUT THE BALKAN PROBLEM THEN MUTTERED STEVE TURNERS POEM HISTORY LESSON HISTORY REPEATS ITSELF HAS TO NO ONE LISTENS I COULDNT GET ANYTHING MORE OUT OF HIM EXCEPT SOME COMMENT ABOUT WORKING BACKWARDS THROUGH THE PAPERS SO I TURNED MY ATTENTION BACK TO THE SAFE THE MECHANISM WAS BIGGER AND HEAVIER THAN WE WERE USED TO AND HAD BEEN EXQUISITELY MADE THE COMPONENTS SLID ALMOST NOISELESSLY OVER ONE ANOTHER AND THE LOUD CLICKS I HAD HEARD WHEN MOVING THE TABLE SEEMED TO BE THE RESULT OF A BROKEN COG TOOTH CATCHING ON THE BARRELS THAT MADE IT EVEN HARDER TO OPEN WHAT LITTLE NOISE THE LOCK TUMBLERS MADE WAS HEAVILY DISGUISED AND WE HAD TO RESORT TO DRILLING A SMALL ACCESS HOLE TO PASS AN ENDOSCOPE INTO THE INTERIOR IT WAS AS WELL WE HAD TAKEN THE EFFORT SITTING IN THE MIDDLE OF A PILE OF NOTEBOOKS AND PAPERS WAS A SMALL PILE OF WHAT LOOKED LIKE EXPLOSIVES THE SAFE WAS RIGGED TO BLOW IF WE MADE A MISTAKE

I wouldn't put grammar in there for a 500 rep bounty.

Comment: How did you find the key so fast? Is there any website that brute forces it?

Comment: @S.M. https://www.guballa.de/vigenere-solver (yes.)